# Does android provide HTML like support

Tags: android

Does android provide any *field **name attribute*** or like form names attribute *as in HTML* so that values *could be read on the next page using these attribute names* as done using HTML ?

Comment: If you're asking about developing an HTML specific app, then try using PhoneGap. Also, Android supports HTML files that can be viewed using a `WebView`.

Comment: Thanks JoelFernandes ! I want to make a login activity in android that could call a login service for authentication (which my desktop site calls and that service automatically reads the values entered in webpage  using name attribute of form tag and text/password field). I want the same service to authenticate the request from android.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse yes. If I understood your questions right, you are asking about field names in forms or any thing you have in your application as in HTML we add name="" and id="" etc., right?

If that's the question then yes, Android supports such attributes to each entity in an Activity.

Ex:

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/My_TextView_ID/NAME_here"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="I am a TextView" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/My_Button_ID/NAME_here"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="I am a Button" />
```

Now you can use this in any activity you wish to. Hope this helps. Else chuck it.

Comment: Thanks Harish ! what if all controls in my HTML are inside a form tag ? What is equal to form in android ...plz read my comment in main question above

Comment: So basically you write the layout for the login form you need and then write an activity for the login form. There is nothing equivalent to a <form> tag in Android but you will have to simply add all the fields which are EditText and TextView. For example of a login form activity visit [link]http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/[/link]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Html.formatHtml(your html code);
```

If you want to show html in textview, just use this:

```
textview.setText(Html.formatHtml(your html code));
```

Answer (score -2):

look at this link, this will help you [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

You can add the javascript interface like this

> you can include the following class in your Android application:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
     Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
   @JavascriptInterface
     public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

> Adding this javascript interface to webview

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

> calling iterface from html input tag

```
  <input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    Android.showToast(toast);
  }
```

Comment: This kind of link-only answer is not acceptable because it seems more like a comment instead.